# mysql IF in GROUP BY clause

Tags: mysql, if-statement, group-by

Is there a way do the if in group by clause?

I have a query where I want to group the result based on the value of a column

if the column is Null, i want the result to remain as it is but if not, i want to group it by that value? how do you do that?

edit: sorry I think i should put a more specific example

the columns below contains the id of category, thread and reply

it's for a forum

the ones with null values means they don't have any reply in them

if the reply is null, i don't want to group it

**the purpose is for counting the replies and the threads inside a category**

i did not set the value for reply to be null, they are like that because of the result of a join

```
| category | thread | reply   |
-------------------------------
| 1        | 1      | 1       |
| 1        | 1      | 2       |
| 1        | 2      | 3       |
| 2        | 3      | 4       |
| 3        | 4      | 5       |
| 3        | 4      | 6       |
| 4        | 5      | null    |
| 5        | 6      | null    |
```

then the result would be

```
| category | thread | reply |
-----------------------------
| 1        | 3      | 3     |
| 2        | 1      | 1     |
| 3        | 2      | 2     |
| 4        | 1      | null  |
| 5        | 1      | null  |
```

Comment: just use group by  i dont think it is necessary to check if it is null or not.

Comment: you must show us the join you use to get that result, it can be done on that join.

Answer (score 16):

You can actually include a CASE statement in a GROUP BY or ORDER BY clause:

```
ORDER BY CASE
            WHEN reply IS NULL THEN 1  
            ELSE 0 
         END, category
```

Answer (score 4):

As of mysql 5.6 you can use a IF() in the order by clause.

Like this:

```
ORDER BY IF(reply=NULL, 1, 0), category
```

Maybe not the right answer for your specific case, but handy for other people searching for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right try this way:

```
(
SELECT category, COUNT(thread) AS thread, COUNT(reply) AS reply
  FROM test
  WHERE reply IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY category
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT category, COUNT(thread) AS thread, reply
  FROM test
  WHERE reply IS NULL
  GROUP BY category
)
ORDER BY category
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5edc3d/1)

Comment: I will try this, hope it works, I have a pretty complicated query, for now I'm using multiple view table as temporary solution but i want a better query to use

Answer (score 0):

MySQL will group all rows with fr=null into one, just as if it was a normal value.

To solve your problem I would do a sub select of your table where a new column either got the value of fr (in the case where it's not null) or a incremented value well out of the normal scope of fr, perhaps negative numbers. And then do the outer selects group by on that new virtual column.

```
set @i := 0;

select if(virtualFR<0,null,virtualFR) as fr, sum(fr_sum) from
(select *, if(fr is null,@i:=@i-1,fr) as virtualFR from myTable) virtual
group by virtualFR;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff2a4/16)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
select min(id) id, sum(fr_sum) fr_sum, fr
from mytable
group by 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using **[Group By](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)**

```
select 
min(id), 
sum(fr_sum), 
fr
from Table1
group by fr
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04014/1)**